# How to improve nodejs / socket io performance?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, websocket, socket.io

I have set up a server for a little game. The clients send their movement data in a certain interval to the server. The server sends data about the other players, also in a certain interval, to the clients. If I add more players, the performance gets worse. How can I improve the performance now?

Does sending single attributes instead of objects increase the speed?

Can I create a more stable performance by using a bigger interval?

Or do you have other ideas?

And is there a debugging tool to check which server actions slow the server down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually improve performance in three ways :

**1 - Reduce the size of instructions you send on the socket.**

You can achieve this by :

- Minimify your JSON
- Use [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/) which is smaller than JSON

**2 - Send just what you need.**

- If you need to move the player, you just need to send the position.
- If you need to pop a new player, then send the complete object and store it client-side.
- ...

**3 - Reduce the frequency.**

You don't need to send every positions.
You can, for example, send a player position every second. On the client, you will then need to add an animation which moves the player to the position with an animation that lasts one second.
[Here's an article that well explains game networking techniques](http://drewblaisdell.com/writing/game-networking-techniques-explained-with-pong/)